# Find all Rows for a given date

Tags: pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a Dataframe like this:

```
Datum                                  X
...                              
2013-01-08 14:00:00  14:00:00         38
2013-01-08 14:15:00  14:15:00         70
2013-01-08 14:30:00  14:30:00         70
2013-01-08 14:45:00  14:45:00         71
2013-01-09 15:00:00  15:00:00         69
....
```

iam trying to extract all Rows with a given date:

```
date = pandas.to_datetime('2013-01-08')
dff = dataframe.loc[date]
```

but i get:

KeyError: 'the label [2013-01-08 00:00:00] is not in the [index]'

and if try:

```
    dff = dataframe.loc[date.date()]
```

KeyError: 'the label [2013-01-08] is not in the [index]'

but as you see, i have rows with the date 2013-01-08...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using`.date` for both

```
df[df.index.date==date.date()]
Out[188]: 
                     X
Datum                 
2013-01-08 14:00:00  1
2013-01-08 14:15:00  2
2013-01-08 14:30:00  3
2013-01-08 14:45:00  4
```